# iOS animation sync

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I have a song and a [portative](http://i41.tinypic.com/wj6fzp.png) . I would like to color the portative accordingly to the song's progress, as the song plays . ( Something like a progress bar , only , over the each portative ) . I really don't know where to look for something like this . Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question you want each note to become a star as it plays.

You're going to need a set of timings... so maybe a plist for each song containing an entry for each note, with it's start time, length and pitch(?), which you could load into an array.

From this you can draw your musical notation - using Core Graphics to draw the stave, and place an image for each note in the correct place. Start playing the song, and using your array of timings, fire a timer for each note, and as the timer fires, add a star over the note, and animate the alpha from 0 to 1, using the length of the note as the duration.

How does that sound?